# Styling a <select> menu

Tags: html, css, forms

I have a select menu like this:

```
<select name="mySelect">
    <option value="250" selected="selected">250</option>
    <option value="500">500</option>
    <option value="1000">1000</option>
    <option value="1500">1500</option>
</select>
```

It comes out looking different depending on OS and I would like it to have a different background. The problem is when I use a standard css background the arrow on the right of the select element remains visible.

```
select {
  background: url(../images/bg_select.png);
}
```

I would also like to have different background colours when the select list has been opened. The default is often blue and white.

**Edit:** Looks like I'll have to use javascript. Are there any jQuery plugins to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to look at this: [Cut & Paste DHTML Select menu](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/dhtmlcombo.shtml). It uses Javascript to replace the select menu with custom HTML.

Answer (score 0):

all a listener to the select and use jquery to trigger the class
add/remove classes should work fine